lstdefinestyle code will not center in middle of document
I have some python code that I cannot center in the middle of the page as if you would do \centering. But none of the center commands work.
this is my code.
Apologies for the long preamble, whenever I remove a package the code is no longer formatted so I am playing it safe and including all.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{transparent}

\usepackage[labelfont=bf, skip=5pt, font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%for tables
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{everypage-1x}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % load both xcolor and colortbl
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.56cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[top=1cm,bottom=1cm,left=1cm,landscape]{geometry}

\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}% <-- new
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}
%\input{arrowsnew}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{everypage-1x}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.0}

\lstdefinestyle{pythonStyle}{
    language=Python,
    backgroundcolor=\color{white},   % background color for code block
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize, % basic font style
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},         % color for keywords
    commentstyle=\color{darkgreen},    % color for comments (darker green)
    stringstyle=\color{red},           % color for strings
    numbers=left,                      % show line numbers
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},     % style for line numbers
    stepnumber=1,                      % step between two line numbers
    numbersep=5pt,                     % distance of line numbers from code
    showspaces=false,                  % don't show spaces
    showstringspaces=false,            % don't emphasize spaces in strings
    showtabs=false,                    % don't show tab characters
    breaklines=true,                   % automatic line breaking
    breakatwhitespace=true,            % break lines at whitespace
    tabsize=4,                         % tab size
    captionpos=b,                      % caption position bottom
    escapeinside={\%*}{*)},            % for LaTeX inside code
    columns=flexible                   % align numbers better
}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=pythonStyle]
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 
              2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 
              2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 
              2020, 2021, 2022])
y = np.array([25, 24.6, 24.1, 24.2, 28.2, 25.1, 24.9, 25.3, 26.3, 25.2, 
              27.2, 22.5, 27.1, 25.5, 26.1, 27.1, 27.7, 27.6, 24.4, 27.3, 
              25.9, 26.9, 27, 27.1, 25, 30.3, 26.6, 26.1, 28.6, 29.1, 
              25.5, 26.2, 26.5])

m, b = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)

y_pred = m * x + b

ss_res = np.sum((y - y_pred) ** 2)  
ss_tot = np.sum((y - np.mean(y)) ** 2)  
r_squared = 1 - (ss_res / ss_tot)

print(f"Slope: {m}")
print(f"Intercept: {b}")
print(f"R-squared: {r_squared}")
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}



"Apologies for the long preamble, " you really shoudl always minimise that before posting here, just delete each line and check the example still shows the problem, your example doesn't use tikz at all so why have \usepackage{tikz} it just makes it harder for peopel to trace. Butanyway listings, verbatim and similar packages all make a full width text block so centering, raggedright, etc make no difference, to have a narrower block that you then center put listings in a minipaghe (of say .75\textwidth) and put the minipage in a center

Ok in future I delete before hand. Also are you able to explain further how I can change the code to center the code. Much appreciated.
